# MergeMap operator does not guarantee order. Is there a better way?

Tags: rxjs

Consider the following:

```
import { timer, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

(function(){

    var sub$ = new Subject<number>();
    var complete = false;

    var out$ = sub$.pipe(
        mergeMap(n => {
            complete = n === 7;
            if (complete) {
                return of(n);
            } else {
                return timer(1000).pipe(map(() => n));
            }
        })
    );

    out$.subscribe({
        next: (n) => console.log(n)
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        sub$.next(i);
    }

    sub$.complete();

})();
```

Even though the values broadcasted by the subject, in order, are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, the output of the above code is:

> 7
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6

How can this pipe be organized differently to assure order despite internal delays?

Comment: just use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

Comment: @Nam I can see why intuitively concatMap makes sense but when I reviewed concatMap along with others neither the docs or Rxjs Marbles explains it in a way that shows it maintains order.   It does fix the problem.  You should post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @RTD learnrxjs.io isn't an official documentation. Here it says https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concatMap *"in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next.*

Comment: @RTD sure, I can create an official answer using the official document suggested by martin as well

Comment: @martin I don't know where you got learnrxjs.io from.  Look at the docs.  The diagram doesn't clearly show a scenario that preserves order.  It would be more straightforward to say "preserve order" than "in a serialized fashion."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap` to achieve this https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concatMap

Answer (score 0):

use `timer(1000).pipe(map(() => n))` instead of `of(n)`.
or use `endWith` operator